# I'm trying to iterate through an unknown number of inputs but keep getting a syntax error on my else statement. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to solve a hackerrank problem that requires us to create a phonebook by giving us an unknown number of inputs.(Using a dictionary or map data structure)
The first input is an integer n that states the number of entries in our phone book, i.e. sam 123421, josh 432143 would be 2.

The next n inputs are the phone entries in the format of two strings i.e. sam 123421

Finally, an unknown number of inputs follows this. The inputs are string values in the form of names. i.e sam, josh, etc.

We must return the output in the form of:

```
sam=123421
josh=432143
```

If the name is not found in the phonebook, we must print out Not Found:

```
sam=123421
josh=432143
Not Found
```

I have written a segment of code, i want to test it but I keep getting a syntax error on my else statement...

Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
n = int(input())
di = dict()
for i in range(n):
    x = input().split()
    di[x[0]] = x[1]

try:
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line in di:
            print('{}={}'.format(line,di.get(line))
        else:
            print('Not Found')        
except EOFError:
    pass
```

I keep getting a File "Solution.py", line 13
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax error message.

Comment: `print('{}={}'.format(line,di.get(line))` you have 3 `(` but only 2 `)`....

Comment: Hey thanks so much. I don't know how I missed that. Also to whoever helped me format my question, thanks! I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error, you need to add an extra parenthesis:

```
if line in di:
   print('{}={}'.format(line,di.get(line))
else:
   print('Not Found')
```

The second line here is missing a closing parenthesis. Replace it with this:

```
print('{}={}'.format(line,di.get(line)))
```

Comment: @EddieZeng It's okay, it happens to everyone ;)

Comment: I pressed the tick next to the comment, does that make it the accepted answer? sorry I'm new

Comment: @EddieZeng Yup, thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Missing right paranthesis

```
print('{}={}'.format(line,di.get(line)))
```